# AngularJS Basic Authentication

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having an issue where adding the `Authentication` header causes angular to stop working. Here is my controller code:

```js
app.controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $http) {
    var url = 'http://my.api.domain';
    $scope.login = function () {
        var headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic base64username:email'};
        $http({
            url: url + '/login',
            method: "GET",
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: headers
        });
    }
});
```

I've gone through all the CORS troubleshooting steps and I don't think that's it. Angular simply won't make the request when I set the headers, but it will if the headers are not set.

Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: It gives no error message in the console?

Comment: @mason no there's nothing.

Comment: Did you look at what you need to do for [basic authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)? Seems like you need to do some base 64 encoding.

Comment: @mason Yeah I did and it's encoding fine. No matter what I set the value of the `Authorization` header to, the request just does not send.

Comment: What do you mean it's encoding fine? What does the resulting HTTP request look like?

Comment: @mason That's the problem. There is no HTTP request. If my username/password are barry.allen@gmail.com/Flash01, then the `headers` object is `{ Authorization: "Basic YmFycnkuYWxsZW5AZ21haWwuY29tOkZsYXNoMDE=" }`. Everything runs fine up to the request, and `$http` even returns a promise, but no request is ever sent.

Comment: Adding other headers such as `X-Testing` also causes the request to fail, but overwriting existing headers such as `Content-Type` does not.

Comment: Works in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wyjuz08m/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was that angular was first requesting API information via an `OPTIONS` request and that response from the server was incorrect (it was returning the incorrect `Access-Control-Accept-Headers` value). It took me a while to figure it out because I was using Firefox and Firebug to debug and for some reason it wasn't logging or displaying `OPTIONS` requests. Running on Chrome or Edge will show the problem though.